# Looking for information about a comic book bound collection (various themes)

Tags: identification-request, comics

Maybe someone could make sense of my recollection. I used to have a hardcover bound comic book collection/anthology. It had the word "Annual" as part of the title.

It didn't belong to any familiar franchise (DC/Marvel).
The themes were more adult and realistic-like and none of them were sci-fi/fantasy per-se, at least most of them weren't.
The themes I do remember:

- In English.
- WWI/WWII soldiers and tanks.
- Vintage race cars (e.g. Lotus F1 series). I remember it akin to A-HA's "Take on me" style  . See images below for both references.
- I'm quite sure at least some were b&w.

[image]
[image]
I used to have this collection back in the 80s and even then it felt old, so it probably was.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the images of? Also, please see the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and if any of the questions there jog your memory, [edit] more details into your question

Comment: The car is the Lotus I mentioned. The image taken is an illustration of the style I remember and also contains the look and feel of the drivers. It is taken from the videoclip I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

In the [UK 'Annuals'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_publication#United_Kingdom) are hardback special editions of weekly comics published around the year end, in time for the Christmas market ensuring lots of sales as gifts. It seems likely this is the type of publication you are talking about.

It is impossible to know *which* comic or boys' paper you had an Annual for, or indeed which year, from the information you have given, but it could have been something like [The Eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_(British_comics)).

Comment: Thank you! It makes perfect sense. Are those editions considered rare?

Comment: I am sure there will be some that are considered rare, but I really have no specialist knowledge. I just used to be a kid that got Annuals at Christmas.